# Creating a custom Activity in Python

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, python

I have built a custom activity following the tutorial here:

https://github.com/sfmc-developer-advocates/custom-activity-deskapi-node

This works fine, but it is written in node.js which I have very limited knowledge on. Does anyone have directions on how to do this in python? How do I get around using post monger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement the backend of the activity using any python based REST-framework, for example [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#api-guide). However, I'm afraid I cannot think of any solution that would get you around using postmonger and the frontend-javascript code in the public-folder of the activity.

**Python REST-Frameworks I found:**

- [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#api-guide)
- [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html)
- [Falcon](http://falconframework.org/)
- [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)